# How To Write A Function That Puts Text In A Paragraph

Tags: javascript, html, css, function

I have to create a second button/input box on the page, underneath the green paragraph square where the text has to appear. How do I write the function to get the text centered in the paragraph? I have to use document.getElementById to get the input box object and the paragraph object. Here is what I have so far:

HTML:

```
</head>
  <body>
   <div>
     <button onclick="sayMagicWord();">Press For Magic </button>
  </div>
      
<p></p>
    <div>
        <input id ="inputbox" type ="text" size ="10" value="Enjoy your semester at Fordham"/>
        <button onclick="enjoy();">Click To Place Text In Paragraph </button>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
p {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: green;
    margin-left: 20px
}
```

JS:

```
function sayMagicWord() {
alert("PLEASE");
}

function enjoy() {

}
```

And here are the instructions from my prof if this makes it clearer:

1. On the HTML page, add a paragraph with a green background and a width and height 200px X 200px below the first button on the page. (Use a separate css file for styling the paragraph by id )
2. On the HMTL page, create an input box and another button side-by side and below the paragraph
3. Associate a second function with the new button. On the javascript file page, create that function. Inside that function, take the text from the input box and place it centered inside the paragraph ( Make use of css also). Give the paragraph and input box  an id
   Use document.getElementById command  to get the input box object, and the paragraph object
   Then assign the value of the textbox entry to the innerHTML of the paragraph

Comment: Centering it has nothing to do with `document.getElementById` - note that your prof wrote "Make use of css also" in regards to the centering...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you need to set an id for the paragraph first. Lets say `<p id='e'> </p>` , though you can name it whatever you want. Then, in your javascript file, you can tap into the document, then get the ID of the paragraph (in this case, e) and use the method innerHTML() to set the paragraph to the value of the textbox
This would be:

```
function enjoy() {
 document.getElementById('e').innerHTML = 'value here';
}
```

As for the CSS, refer to
https://www.w3schools.com/csS/css_align.asp

Try to look at pages like w3schools guide on things like the document object model, or its methods. As its homework, some research would go a long way.

Comment: Thanks so much!! I was struggling with how to figure out referring to the paragraph and forgot about ids. This was super helpful